# Chrome does not allow me installing my extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wonder why I cannot drop my extension folder into extensions tab. Developer mode is enabled and I have done it before many times!

Chrome does not allow dropping (it used to open a section to drop it there) :)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: It shows an error when it's not working, what does it say ?

Comment: added in the question.

Comment: A _folder_? As in, an unpacked extension? Didn't know it even could do that. The usual way is to click "Load unpacked extension" and selecting the folder.

Comment: What's your question? How to do it now that it does not work, or why it doesn't work/how to make it work again?

Comment: Well, i used to drag and drop and used to work pretty well. But let's try your method, too.

Comment: @Xan I could drag & drop a folder as well.

Comment: And I could only "Load unpacked extension"! weird! Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even know it was possible to do it this way. I thought drag&drop was only for CRX installs (that Google tries to ban).

The "usual" way is to enable Developer mode, then click "Load unpacked extension" and select the folder.

Comment: +1 as this works as an alternative way, but I am still curious why this is not working for me (drag & drop)  but used to do, and of course that was more comfortable.

Comment: Like I said, Google is trying to extinguish CRX-based installs. It would make sense that they disable drag&drop. That said, which OS and which version of Chrome?

Comment: version: 43.0.2357.130

Comment: I restarted the PC, and now it's working fine -> drag&drop works fine.